# How can I refresh Trimesh(Pyglet) viewer to see my mesh(stl) rotation and interupt this visualisation after an angular condition?

Tags: python-3.x, rotation, page-refresh, pyglet, trimesh

After long hours to search by myself a solution to my question, I am here to find some help so that, I hope, someone could help me to unfreeze my actual situation. So if there is any specialist or nice "Python Guru" who has some time to give me a hand on it, here is the context :

I am working on a mesh manipulation script thanks to the wonderful Trimesh library on Python 3.6 and I would like, while applying some matrix rotation transformation, to refresh the mesh visualisation in order to see the real time rotation evolution of the mesh.

Without success, I did some try following the hereinbelow script found on the Trimesh GitHub but I am not able to stop it without clicking on the upper right "closing cross". Here is the original code:

```py
"""
view_callback.py
------------------

Show how to pass a callback to the scene viewer for
easy visualizations.
"""

import time
import trimesh
import numpy as np


def sinwave(scene):
    """
    A callback passed to a scene viewer which will update
    transforms in the viewer periodically.

    Parameters
    -------------
    scene : trimesh.Scene
      Scene containing geometry

    """
    # create an empty homogenous transformation
    matrix = np.eye(4)
    # set Y as cos of time
    matrix[1][3] = np.cos(time.time()) * 2
    # set Z as sin of time
    matrix[2][3] = np.sin(time.time()) * 3

    # take one of the two spheres arbitrarily
    node = s.graph.nodes_geometry[0]
    # apply the transform to the node
    scene.graph.update(node, matrix=matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create some spheres
    a = trimesh.primitives.Sphere()
    b = trimesh.primitives.Sphere()

    # set some colors for the balls
    a.visual.face_colors = [255, 0, 0, 255]
    b.visual.face_colors = [0, 0, 100, 255]

    # create a scene with the two balls
    s = trimesh.Scene([a, b])

    # open the scene viewer and move a ball around
    s.show(callback=sinwave)
```

And here is my try to integrate a matrix rotation transformation (to apply rotation on the imported mesh) to see the evolution.
But the rotation is not smooth (the animation is crenellated) and I am not able to stop it automatically lets say after a 97° rotation on z. (And the code is based on time while I would like it to be based on angular position).

```py
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
import time
import xlsxwriter

import numpy as np

import trimesh
from trimesh import transformations as trf

# Actual directory loading and stl adress saving
actual_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
stl = Path(actual_dir/"Belt_Bearing_Gear.stl")

mesh = trimesh.load(f"{stl}")


def R_matrix(scene):

    u= 0
    o= 0
    t= time.time()

    time.sleep(0.1)

    rotation = (u, o, t)

    # Angle conversion from degres to radian
    def trig(angle):
        r = np.deg2rad(angle)
        return r

    alpha = trig(rotation[0])
    beta = trig(rotation[1])
    gamma = trig(rotation[2])

    origin, xaxis, yaxis, zaxis = [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]

    Rx = trf.rotation_matrix(alpha, xaxis)
    Ry = trf.rotation_matrix(beta, yaxis)
    Rz = trf.rotation_matrix(gamma, zaxis)

    R = trf.concatenate_matrices(Rx, Ry, Rz)           
    R2=R[:3,:3]


    # The rotation matrix is applyed to the mesh
    mesh.vertices = np.matmul(mesh.vertices,R2)


    # apply the transform to the node
    s = trimesh.Scene([mesh])

    scene.graph.update(s, matrix=R)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # set some colors for the mesh and the bounding box
    mesh.visual.face_colors = [102, 255, 255, 255]

    # create a scene with the mesh and the bounding box
    s = trimesh.Scene([mesh])
    liste=list(range(1,10))

    # open the scene viewer and move a ball around
    s.show(callback=R_matrix)
```

All your ideas and suggestions are welcome since I am a young Python beginner :)
Thanks in advance for your help,
Warm regards,

RV